# Instrumenting Java 9+ runtime modules

Tags: java, java-9, instrumentation, java-11

Our tool (http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon) calculates program invariants by inserting instrumentation into the Java byte codes for a program.  The *user* code is instrumented during runtime via the normal `ClassFileTransformer::transform` method.

It is also necessary to track value flows through *JDK* methods. Thus, we need to instrument the Java runtime as well. We cannot use `transform`, because hundreds of runtime methods are loaded prior to the first time we get control at `transform`.

Prior to Java 9, we handled this in an offline step that reads `rt.jar`, instruments its methods, and writes out a modified version as `dcomp-rt.jar`.   The user placed `dcomp-rt.jar` on the bootclasspath to ensure our modified Java runtime methods were loaded instead of the standard ones.  The user program invocation would look something like:

```
java -cp .:.../daikon/daikon.jar \
  -Xbootclasspath/p:.../daikon/java/dcomp_rt.jar:.:.../daikon/daikon.jar \
  -javaagent:.../daikon/java/dcomp_premain.jar={various dcomp arguments} \
  {user program} {user program arguments}
```

Now to Java 9+.  Our first approach was to read in and instrument the class files within the Java runtime jmod files (via the new `jrt:/` file system) and create a `dcomp_rt.jar` as before.  The problem we are experiencing is that we cannot get the system to use the contents of this jar instead of `jrt:/java.base` (for example).  We tried various `--module-path` and `-Xbootclasspath` (only `/a` is available now, might be part of problem) options to no avail.  Still hoping there might be a way to do this?

If not, I'm guessing we need to make modified versions of each of the interesting runtime jmods and then use a `--patch-module` argument for each of them.  Would this ensure our modified code is loaded instead of the standard runtime?

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps “you’re holding it wrong”? All “values into and out of Java runtime calls” can be tracked by only instrumenting the application code which does call into the Java runtime and potentially gets called by the Java runtime. Instrumenting all Java runtime classes leads to a lot of internal calls you have to filter out, so two times doing unnecessary work…

Comment: The --patch-module option is the module equivalent to -Xbootclasspath/p when you need to override classes in the run-time image. It should work here although you need to be careful if you are instrumenting classes in java.base to access classes that are outside of java.base. Have you considered writing a java agent and using -javaagent instead of static instrumentation? If you really want to do static instrumentation then you could instrument the code in the packaged modules (jmod files) and then run jlink to create a new run-time image with the instrumented modules.

Comment: As (not well) indicated above, we do use a javaagent to do instrumentation.  The problem is all the java runtime classes that get loaded before we see the first class via 'transform'.  Not having those 'early loaded' classes instrumented can make our invariant analysis less accurate.  As you point out (and my experiment noted in my own answer below) --patch-module does the job.  The instrumented code does access some of our own classes outside of java.base.  What are the issues here?

Comment: @MarkRoberts coundn't that be solve by an agent that can retransform classes?

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like --patch-module does the trick.  I made the same dcomp_rt.jar but with only classes from java.base.jmod.  Then used:

```
 --patch-module java.base={full path}/dcomp_rt.jar
```

Running java with -verbose:class showed all base classes being loaded from my jar.

Is this the best way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Assuming dcomp_rt.jar only contains instrumented versions of the classes from java.base then you should be okay. If you've got classes from other modules in this JAR file then it will not work.

Comment: The problem is that the instrumentation we add includes calls to our runtime routines to capture the invariant data.  Using retransform is a good idea, but won't work in our case as we add new methods to the class we are instrumenting.

Comment: So assuming there is no way for the base module to reference methods not included in the base module(?) I see a couple of avenues to pursue.  One is see if we can create a fully self-contained runtime and then add it to the base module.  Another is to look into your suggestion of using jlink to build our own runtime.

Comment: If you are statically instrumenting classes that are used early in the startup then you may be playing with fire as the VM is limited to java.base until it is fully initialized. JVMTI agents can enable a capability for CFLH events in the primordial phase but there is no equivalent for java agents. Another thing is that you can't instrument code in modules mapped to the boot class loader with references to code on the class path. It's not clear from your comments where your "runtime routines" are deployed.